# Starting Solr 7.2.1 with startup parameters on Windows via Cygwin

Tags: windows, solr, cygwin

I'm upgrading Solr 4.3.1 to Solr 7.2.1

I used to start Solr 4.3.1 like so:

```
C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash -c "cd /cygdrive/c/Databases/solr-4.3.1/example/;java -Dsolr.solr.home="./example-DIH/solr/" -jar -Xms200m -Xmx1600m start.jar -OPTIONS=jsp"
```

However, when I try this:

```
C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash -c "cd /cygdrive/c/Databases/solr-7.2.1/example/;java -Dsolr.solr.home="./example-DIH/solr/" -jar -Xms200m -Xmx1600m start.jar -OPTIONS=jsp"
```

> Error: Unable to access jarfile start.jar

I then copy `start.jar` from C:\Databases\solr-4.3.1\example to C:\Databases\solr-7.2.1\example

And re-run the .bat file, but then I get

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No XML configuration files specified in
>   start.config or command line.
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:506)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:95)
>
> Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
>          java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information

However, in my old Solr environment I don't see a start.config either and I'm passing the same parameters over the command line.

Without Cygwin I can start Solr successfully:

> C:\Databases\solr-7.2.1\bin>solr.cmd start -p 8984
>   Waiting up to 30 to see Solr running on port 8984
>   Started Solr server on port 8984. Happy searching!

**UPDATE 1**

@Holger below pointed out there's a `server` folder. I have that folder and there's already a `start.jar` file in there.

So I tried:
`bash -c "cd /cygdrive/C/Databases/solr-7.2.1/server/;java -Dsolr.solr.home="solr/" -jar -Xms200m -Xmx1600m start.jar -OPTIONS=jsp"`

But then I get:

> WARNING: System properties and/or JVM args set.  Consider using --dry-run or --exec
>   WARNING: Nothing to start, exiting ...

How can I start Solr 7.2.1 (on Windows) via Cygwin with additional parameters (like memory allocation)

Comment: Can you start Solr 7.2.1 without using Cygwin ?

Comment: @matzeri yes, see my latest post addition

Comment: "Nothing to start" propably means -Dsolr.solr.home is wrong. I suppose it should have been something like "../example-DIH/solr/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems as I updated from 4.x to 7.x, but on OS X.

Is there a directory ../solr-7.2.1/server? Then try with start.jar not in

```
../solr-7.2.1/example
```

but in

```
../solr-7.2.1/server.
```

The working directory has to be the directory containing start.jar. So be in

```
 ../solr-7.2.1/server
```

when starting solr. You propably have to set

```
--module=http -Dsolr.log.dir=...
```

too. This is what worked for me.

Note the release notes for Release 5.2.0  [2015-06-07]

"It is no longer possible to run "java -jar start.jar" from inside the server directory.  The bin/solr script is the only supported way to run Solr. This is necessary to support  HTTP and HTTPS modules in Jetty which can be selectively enabled by the bin/solr scripts.  In case you have a pressing need to run solr the old way, you can run  "java -jar start.jar --module=http" to get the same behavior as before."